# How to pass value from Broadcast receiver to Activity in android?

Tags: android

I am developing the sample application in android.I want to know how to pass the variable from broadcast receiver to to the Activity class

Please any one help me how to do that in android
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Intent` to start an `Activity`, 
 then send values to the intent by using `intent.putExtra(key, value)` and get the same in your `Activity`.