# Android fail to pass variable from broadcast receiver to other class

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Hey I am working on app that need to pass variable receive from broadcastreceiver to the service class

I have see this post 
[How to pass value from Broadcast receiver to Activity in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184437/how-to-pass-value-from-broadcast-receiver-to-activity-in-android)
but its not work.

Here is my code

```
public class BatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
int batteryLevel;
int batteryScale;
private int status;
private boolean isCharging;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("test battery", "battery:" + batteryLevel);
    batteryLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
    batteryScale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 0);

    //Log.v("charging state", "state:" + isCharging);
    status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL||status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;

    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);      
    service.putExtra("BatteryLevel", batteryLevel);
    service.putExtra("BatteryScale", batteryScale);
    service.putExtra("Charging", isCharging);
context.startService(service);
}

}
```

The service class to receive the 3 variable

```
public class MyService extends Service {
int batteryLevel;
int batteryScale;
private boolean isCharging;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    batteryLevel = intent.getIntExtra("BatteryLevel", batteryLevel);
    batteryScale = intent.getIntExtra("BatteryScale", batteryScale);
    isCharging = intent.getBooleanExtra("Charging", isCharging);

    Log.v("test battery", "battery:" + batteryLevel);
    Log.v("charging state", "state:" + isCharging);

           //other method

           return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

At the end the log always show the batterylevel is 0 and charging state is false, which means the varibale not pass to sercive

As people guide me i have assign the value to the variable as show above, but this still not work

here is my mainfest, I think there might be something wrong here

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MyApp">
    </activity>

    <service 
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true">
    </service>

    <receiver 
        android:name=".BatteryReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

And in receiver part the eclispe return "Exported receiver does not require permission"

In my app the service will keep run in backgroud and try to receive the variable from braodcastreceiver to perform the function

I am not sure which part I do wrong, if you spot the error plase let me know, thank you very much.

Comment: Have you declared the service in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: in the service you're not assigning values, since they are ints the default value is 0, if they were Objects you would have gotten  a nullpointer exception.

Comment: @Dya I have update the question, i think maybe there is something wrong in my mainfest, since after assign value it still not reutrn any value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do something like below, How can you expect Variables having value  without assinging into them

```
batteryLevel   =    intent.getIntExtra("BatteryLevel", batteryLevel);
 batteryScale  =       intent.getIntExtra("BatteryScale", batteryScale);
   isCharging   =       intent.getBooleanExtra("Charging", isCharging);
```

and from where Receiver calling Service.

you should call `startService(intent);` // this intent should be the one u assigned/set values into.

```
intent.putExtra("BatteryLevel", batteryLevel);
intent.putExtra("BatteryScale", batteryScale);
intent.putExtra("Charging", isCharging);
```

like in above code you are setting values into intent but not passing this intent to service, call `startService(intent);` and in service take these values in `onstart()` method

*in the receiver u are setting service name as WifiService.class, and your service name is MyService, how it can be possible. make it single name*

Comment: thanks..anyway this still not work , the log cat still show level as 0 and charging state as false

Comment: I have update my code above, any way its still not work. The receiver can start the service but the service still can not get any value. I try to write the Log in the reciver but it not return anything at all ,the massage never show up

Comment: service.putExtra("BatteryLevel", 55);,  service.putExtra("Charging", true);

paas these values manually, and see if these values are getting printed in Service, If it is printed correctly then you are passing wrong values fron Receiver to Service

Comment: I have change default vaule to other number, but in service it still not recive the vaule, so I think its the boradcast receiver have some problem..

Comment: see last two line of my answer !!

Comment: sorry for the mistake, I change it becuase I dont want confuse people, in my program I do write it as "WifiService"rather than "MyService"